# Interacting with HTML element by text in Selenium Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, text, jupyter-lab

I need to interact with an HTML element with an id such as

```html
<span class="a-button-inner">
    <input name="submit.addToCart" aria-label="Aggiungi al carrello dal venditore VERONCART SRL con prezzo 775,00&nbsp;€
" aria-labelledby="" class="a-button-input" type="submit">
<span id="a-autoid-2-offer-1-announce" class="a-button-text" aria-hidden="true"> Aggiungi al carrello </span>
</span>
```

I have many of this buttons on the site and I must identify them by the numerical text inside the aria label,in this case 775.I have tried
with

```py
wd.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(text()='775')]')
```

and

```py
wd.find_element_by_css_selector('//input[value*='775']')
```

None of them works. I've been stuck on this for days, I'd be grateful I someone could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not far from the solution. To specify the selector in which attribute we want to do the search of the value, instead of using `text()` which mean the text of the input, we use the attribute name, which is `@aria-label`.

```py
wd.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@aria-label, '775')]")
```

Please note to not excluding the `775` to our XPath.

Comment: Thanks,I just tried this but it gives me this error:oSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[text()='775']"}
  (Session info: chrome=102.0.5005.115)

Comment: I think it's because the object has the property"aria-hidden=True" so i cannot find it in the page

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I updated the solution. Please check it.